# file_get_contents('php://input') not working on Laravel+Octane / Swoole

Tags: php, swoole, octane

I'm migrating from Laravel 8 to **Laravel 8 + Octane / Swoole**. All works fine, but  `php://input` always are empty. Also, I check $_POST and $_SERVER values.

`file_get_contents('php://input')` is used by [AWS SNS Message Validator](https://github.com/aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator).

Any alterantive to read `php://input`?

#### PHP code

```
echo "php://input: ".file_get_contents('php://input');
```

#### With PHP-FPM

```
$ curl -i -X POST --data "dataaaa" https://example.com/aws/sns/webhook
php://input: dataaaa
```

#### With Octane+Swoole

```
$ curl -i -X POST --data "dataaaa" https://example.com/aws/sns/webhook
php://input:
```

Comment: `php://input` is built into PHP, those frameworks shouldn't change it.

Comment: I think the same as you, but it is always empty using swoole. With PHP-FPM works fine.

Comment: Note that from the CLI SAPI or builtin webserver that `php://input` stream wrapper is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. See [the manual for details](https://www.php.net/wrappers.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Problem

`php://input` are not available on Swoole. Always are the same running process.

##### Solution: PSR-7 Request

```
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

public function sesSubscriptionWebhook(RequestInterface $request)
{
    // $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); // dont work on swoole
    $input = $request->getBody();
}
```

Of course, with octane, `symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` and `nyholm/psr7` are required for [Laravel PSR-7 requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#psr7-requests).

Also, if your problem is related with **AWS SES**, you need to change `Message::fromRawPostData()` to `Message::fromPsrRequest($request)`.